# Integer from StringBuilder

Tags: java

I have a text file that contains one number, and I'm loading it using this method:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/sheet.cfg"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        textureSize = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This line:

```
textureSize = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
```

Throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16"
```

I understand what the issue is, but how do I fix it? Do I need to create a temporary string to remove the quotations and then get the value of that string and pass it into textureSize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem

```
sb.append('\n');
```

dont do it. `Integer.valueOf` accepts only digits in the input string, new line is not allowed

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! So Java automatically adds quotations to new lines?

Answer (score 5):

`Integer.valueOf` does not allow trailing or leading whitespace characters. Trimming the string before parsing should fix the problem:

```
textureSize = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString().trim());
```

Better yet, remove code that adds newline in the first place.